# TypeScript error in const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to run a code from a github project by running `yarn start` but i am getting failed to compile with this error:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/myname/Documents/Projects/BC/pancakeswap_fork/pancake_clone/pancake-swap-exchange-testnet-master/src/components/Popups/PopupItem.tsx(69,28):
Argument of type 'import("/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/BC/pancakeswap_fork/pancake_clone/pancake-swap-exchange-testnet-master/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/index").Context<import("/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/BC/pancakeswap_fork/pancake_clone/pancake-swap-exchange-testnet-master/node_module...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'React.Context<import("/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/BC/pancakeswap_fork/pancake_clone/pancake-swap-exchange-testnet-master/node_modules/@types/styled-components/index").DefaultTheme>'.  TS2345

    67 |   }, [removeAfterMs, removeThisPopup])
    68 | 
  > 69 |   const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)
       |                            ^
    70 | 
    71 |   let popupContent
    72 |   if ('txn' in content) {
```

I've researched about ThemeContext and found a promising solution ([how to create context for theme with reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965021/how-to-create-context-for-theme-with-reactjs)) but i am unsure on how to implement it.

If it's useful, the variable `theme` is used like this:

```
  return (
    <Popup>
      <StyledClose color={theme.colors.textSubtle} onClick={removeThisPopup} />
      {popupContent}
      {removeAfterMs !== null ? <AnimatedFader style={faderStyle} /> : null}
    </Popup>
```

Thanks for any insight and sorry for the noob q.. i'm new with typescript

Comment: Where are you importing `useContext` from?

Comment: @vera. I am importing it using ```import styled, { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components'```. There is no error message next tot he import statement tho.

Comment: I asked for `useContext`, not `ThemeContext`...

Comment: oh sorry.. i'm importing like this: ```import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'```